# need help in placing a marker for geolocation

Tags: jquery, html, elasticsearch

I need help creating a marker for geo-location

coding:

```
var latLong = response._source.misc.latLong;
    console.log(latLong);
    var getaddress = response._source.misc.address;

    showPosition(latLong);

    function showPosition(geolocation) {
   var img_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
                      +geolocation+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";


        document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML = "<img src='"+img_url+"'>";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing marker parameter for static map url.

Check out the below example.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284
```

The marker is added as "markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318"

you should do something like that. Example http://jsfiddle.net/122cgs5y/